# How do I extract the value of the token from an HTTPRequest?

Tags: json, httprequest, deserialize

I've managed to login to the web and have received a token, but I can't seem to get my JSON.deserialize to give me just the token value. What should I be doing?

```
string sToken = response.getBody();
System.debug('######WebCallouts token: ' + sToken);
Map<String, string> token = (Map<String, string>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(sToken);
```

[image]

The 'Map' isn't working, neither are a few other things I tried. Help please!

I get this response:

[image]

Comment: When you say it isn't working, can you help us understand what that means?

Comment: I've added the response I get.

Comment: You need to use map<string,object>. You can't cast it like you have. Once you get the value from the map you can convert into a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting to the wrong type:

The error says you're casting from `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, String>`.

You're trying to cast the map, but that doesn't impact the values in the map: they're not being coerced into Strings as you might expect. Instead stick with the map of `String` to `Object` and cast the objects you pull out of it:

```
Map<String, Object> tokenMap = JSON.deserializeUntyped(sToken);
String token = (String)tokenMap.get('token');
```